# Send Data from an Activity to a class in Android

Tags: android, class, variables, android-activity

I have this problem :
I have one Activity and two class MyGLSurfaceView , MyGLRenderer

In Activity there is a thread that generates different numbers , and I have to send this variable to MyGLRenderer.

I can't pass this variable through constructor's arguments :/
THere is a different mode to send variable from an activity to a class ? How can I do ?

Comment: Create a method in `MyGLRenderer` that allows the activity to send the value.

Comment: The problem is that in Activity there isn't a MyGLRenderer object but only a MyGLRenderer variable.. Therefore The only mode is to implement a function in MyGLSurfaceView that it calls a function of MyGLRenderer ? There isn't other way ?

Maybe Can I do:
myglviewobject.myrendererobject.variable ?

Comment: "MyGLRenderer object but only a MyGLRenderer variable"...umm...sounds like you need to read about what a reference variable is. Or is this a typo in your comment?

Comment: "Maybe Can I do: myglviewobject.myrendererobject.variable" That is certainly one solution. However, it requires very tight coupling which is considered a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's not really clear solution but you can consider using `EventBus`  https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus  which feet to some restricted android-specific situations.

Register `EventBus` in you class constructor like

```
EventBus.getDefault.register(this);
```

and `register()`/`unRegister()` in your activity `onCreate()` and `onDestroy()` methods.

When you need just post value from `activity` like

`EventBus.getDefault().post(new WhateverObject());`

And receive value in other class

```
public void onEvent(WhateverObject object){
//doing stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks :)
Your solution and declare public variable have the same performance ?

Comment: It's not so fast of course(we using it in production with support to minSdk 7 works good), it decoupling activitys and classes very well removing redundant interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

you could change the constructor to match the argument which you send

eg: if you want to pass string

```
MyGLRenderer(String s)
{
// store it to local variable and use it
}
```

or

you could declare a public variable in `MyGLRenderer` class and set it from your `Actvity`

Comment: Thanks to everyone :)

I have chosen the solution of public variable, because I have thought that is much easier solution for me :)